# error in sdk manager visual studio "cannot find central directory"

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, android-sdk-manager

Hello I am parsa when i want to download anything from sdk manager it will give me error for e.g I'm trying to use android emulator and download it's packages but when i want to download them it will show me this[image]

I try to download another packages but it will get me error to and again the error is **"cannot find central directory"**

how should i do to solve it.

Comment: What is the Visual studio version? Please check Android SDK location by **Debug-Option-Xamarin-Android Settings**

Comment: visual studio 2019

Comment: try to repair your visual studio 2019, and see if it woks or not.

Comment: I have tried but it hasn't worked

Answer (score 4):

You have to Use VPN or shecan.ir and change DNS Addresses
Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem too.

I have Instaled

1. Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Version 17.0.0 Preview 6.0
2. Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.11.4 Preview 1.0

And both of them have Xamarin Installed.
I Uninstall Xamarin from both of them, Reinstalled it On VS 2022, and now it's working for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem too. I reinstalled xamarin, using vpn and changing dns address also didn't work.

Then I changed the vpn address from switzerland to america and finally it worked.